# Photoshop "could not complete your request because the destination document cannot accept the layer"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, error

When trying to duplicate a group of coloring files and use them to color a gif/animation, I receive the error message "Could not complete your request because an adjustment or fill layer cannot be converted to the destination document mode".

Can anyone explain why I can't do that or am I missing anything?

I have tried to right click on the group and click Duplicate Group and in the Document list of Destination document, there are only two options which are the same document and New.

When I tried to drag and drop the group I am getting the following error message. I have tried to do all those with just a single color lookup layer and it failed for the same reason as well.

"Could not complete your request because an adjustment or fill layer cannot be converted to the destination document mode".

Any possible causes, or solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: ***Welcome*** to **GD.SE** - Please look through [tour] to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query here, and how best to frame it. As currently framed, your question seems potentially off-topic because it's almost a tech support type question, as it would require access to an individual file or machine; screenshots could help. You might be able to [edit] your question to better fit our guidelines - *please* first read our [help/on-topic] page on what topics are appropriate here - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to move some color fill layers from an RGB document to an Indexed document.

Go to the animation file and from the menu **Image** → **Mode**, check if Indexed is selected. If yes, change it to RGB.

Comment: doesn't work with me, i can't make layers in the new file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Check that quick mask isn't active, and if it is, disable it first.